# How do I make a screen for sharing my screen using A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I wanted to create a screen much like the ones in a cinema using A-Frame, for sharing one's screen.
I have made a plane and added a networked-video-source for easyrtc.

```
<template id="screen-template">
          <a-entity class="screen" networked-audio-source>
            <a-plane position="100 35 0" rotation="0 -90 0" width="200" height="70" color="#FFF" material="side: front" networked-video-source="streamName: screen"></a-plane>
          </a-entity>
        </template>
```

I have added also added a template for the screen with a rotation and position property, but I'm not sure how to add it to the NAF adapter.

The code only renders a screen and on clicking on the screen sharing option the screen remains blank.